# Update score android sdk

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my code,

I would like update score to positiv and negative but the score no update.
thank for you help.

```
int score = 5; 

if(v == findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear))
{
     View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
     ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
     viewgroup.removeView(view);

     //change the text
     String scr = String.valueOf(score++);
     TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
     score1.setText(scr);
}
else if(v == findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear2))
{
     View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
     ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
     viewgroup.removeView(view);

     //change the text
     String scr = String.valueOf(score--);
     TextView score2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
     score2.setText(scr);
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting,post the logcat

Comment: Did you try debugging the app ? Is it even entering the if conditions ?

Comment: I think you are using incorrect way to compare in if() condition. Try comparing ids only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set extra variable and then set score

```
int x = score++;
TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
score1.setText(Integer.toString(score));
```

If it still do not work - you're sure, that your code is going into if or else?

another thing - (I'm not sure with views) you should use in 'if' method "equals" instead of '=='

Comment: String scr = String.valueOf(score++);

         TextView score1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
         
          score1.setText(Integer.toString(score));

Answer (score 0):

Well score++ and score-- are invalid. Check this code:

```
int i = 5;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(i++)); //5
System.out.println(String.valueOf(i--)); //6

i = 5;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(++i)); //6
System.out.println(String.valueOf(--i)); //5
```

Comment: don't you mean 5, 5, 6, 4?

Comment: thank but is the same probleme, the score no update.

Comment: I would like if if(v == findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear)) add 5 and else if(v == findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear2)) add - 3.

Comment: Well I compiled and executed this code and that was the answer. For more info visit http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-increment-decrement-operator/